# Update ListView Selection on button click

Tags: java

https://gyazo.com/dbe9a706e2eaecc34028593636bcf2ea
Here is a picture of an assignment I am working on. I have the add and remove working with no problem. I even had the loan/return button working before I switched to a GUI. Problem is I can not figure out how to update the selected entry on button click. I also can't find any similar problems in google. I don't need the assignment done for me, just a point in the right direction. Thanks for any help.

```
public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
String tempText = listView.getElementAt(listView.getSelectedIndex()).toString();
                mediaCollection.set(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), tempText +     loanedToTextField.getText());

      MediaItem.setLoanedTo(loanedToTextField.getText());
```

Should I not be using ListView?

Comment: You really should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I didn't post my code because I don't want people doing my assignment. Some example code that I can work off of is more than enough.

Comment: But don't you think that people need more than just an image in order to help you? I don't know, but I think that if you give more information it will be easier to people help you.

Comment: I guess so. Personally I can usually go off a picture but I posted a bit of my example code that I'm struggling with.